# How to bind multiple objects using Spring Form with Array?

Tags: java, spring, forms, jstl

I am try to use create a simple test to save multiple objects from my entity using Spring Form:

On model:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

On Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/person/insertMultiple")
public String insertMultiple(Model model) {
    Person[] persons = new Person[3];
    model.addAttribute("persons", persons);
    return "/person/insert_multiple";
}
```

On jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<h1>New Persons</h1>
<form:form action="/person/inserirMultiAction/" method="post" modelAttribute="persons">
    <form:input path="persons[0].name"/>
    <form:input path="persons[0].age"/>
    <form:input path="persons[1].name"/>
    <form:input path="persons[1].age"/>
</form:form>
```

Got this error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Invalid property 'persons[0]' of bean class
>   [[Lcom.mycompany.model.Person;]: Bean property 'persons[0]' is not
>   readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the
>   getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: Person[] person = new Person[3];
    model.addAttribute("persons", persons); passing wrong instance

Comment: In the original code was everything in portuguese, fixed!

Comment: post your Person class

Comment: model included now

Comment: Try ArrayList. `List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: Not working too